# Prove $\sup_Ef_n \rightarrow \sup_Ef$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, uniform-convergence

> Let $\{f_n:E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\}$ be a sequence of functions which uniformly converges to $f$ in $E$.
>
> **Prove:** $$\sup_Ef_n \rightarrow \sup_Ef$$

**Proof:**

By definition of supremum:
$$f_n(x)-f(x)\leq \sup_E|f_n-f|, \ \forall x\in E$$

Rearranging:

$$f_n(x)\leq \sup_E|f_n-f| +f(x)$$

Taking supremum on both sides:

$$\sup_Ef_n(x)\leq \sup_E|f_n-f| +\sup_Ef(x)$$

In symmetric way, we get:

$$\sup_Ef(x)\leq \sup_E|f_n-f| +\sup_Ef_n(x)$$

All together:

$$|\sup_Ef_n(x)- \sup_Ef(x)| \leq \sup_E|f_n-f| \rightarrow 0 $$

---

I'm not sure about the step I took supremum on both sides, so if someone could please verify / correct my proof, I would appreciate it.

Comment: At first you take the supremum on the right-hand-side this makes it larger. Then the right-hand-side is independ of $x$ so you can take the supremum on the left-hand-side as well.

Comment: Yes, your proof looks good.  If $h(x) \leq g(x)$ for all $x \in E$ then indeed $\sup_{x \in E} h(x) \leq \sup_{x \in E} g(x)$, for the reason explained by Nathanael. [Minor typos:  Your last line should have $\sup_E f(x)$ somewhere in the left-hand-side, rather than $|b-b|$. Also $fn$ should be $f_n$ in places]

Comment: In addition to fixing the typos, I suppose your last line only really holds if the individual sups are not infinite.  So you could have "case 1: suppose $\sup_{x \in E} f(x) < \infty$, case 2: Suppose $\sup_{x \in E} f(x) = \infty$."